# ASP.NET don't work onserverclick of anchor

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, anchor

My project worked yesterday.But it isn't anymore.What do you think about why onserverclick of anchor is not working

```
<a class="media-link" href="#" runat="server" onServerClick="sy15">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="descr"><div>
         <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

         <asp:Label ID="Label155" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></div></div>
    </div>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel15" runat="server" Width="654" Height="240">
    <asp:Image ID="Image15" runat="server" ImageUrl="img/urunler/indir.jpg" />

    </asp:Panel>
 </a>
```

C#

```
public void sy15(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     if (Session["kad"] != null)
        Response.Redirect("blogsingle.aspx?Image=" + Image15.ImageUrl + "&kad=" + Label155.Text + "");
     else
        Response.Redirect("register.aspx");
}
```

Comment: where did you hear that `onServerClick` is a thing?

Comment: Shouldn't 'onserverclick' be lower case?

Comment: what does it mean? I use onserverclick when I want to use anchor  like a button event

Comment: I've tried lower case.But it didnt work

Comment: working yesterday and not working anymore means, does it is giving any error today ?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Does postback happen when you click it?

Comment: I tried on my side with `session["something"] != null` and it was redirecting to the page I wanted. Please check and confirm properly. You might be doing some silly mistakes.

**NOTE:-  Silly mistakes like colon and double quotes**

Comment: @Nadeem it doesn't give an error.But all click events dont work.I 've  fix button and linkbutton by CauseValidation=false.But I can't solve problem about anchor like the others.

yes,@Wiizl Postback doesn't happen when I click

Comment: See if there are any errors displayed in browser developer tools. Maybe your markup somewhere else is messed up or there are JS errors. Also if nothing happens try removing `href="#"`

Comment: @Nadeem I'm sure about session,I try after logging in

Comment: Yes @Wiizl it is logical.But it haven't availed

Comment: I just copy-pasted this example into VS - postback works.
Try rolling back some changes...